# Iron-Router checking document existence before route runs

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a basic chat room App where you can create a room from the main page which calls this method :

```
createNewRoom: function (){
    //Room containers unique ID for the object
    var room = Rooms.insert({
        createdAt: new Date()
    });
    return room;
},
```

The rooms are routed like this :

```
Router.route('/rooms/:_id', {
    name: 'room',
    template: 'chatRoom'
});
```

I am trying to set it up though so that you can't just type any random ID and get a room, it has to already exist. So I created this iron-router hook:

```
var checkRoomExists = function() {
    var room = Rooms.findOne({_id : this.params._id});
    if(typeof(room) == "undefined"){
        Router.go('home');
    }
    else {
        this.next();
    }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(checkRoomExists, {
    only : ['room']
});
```

`room` in the `checkRoomExists` always returns undefined though, even if I test the exact same statement elsewhere with the same `_id` and the room exists. So if I send the link to someone else it will redirect even if the room exists. Is this the wrong type of hook or is there a better way to accomplish this?'

Edit some additional information:
This is the code that creates a room the first time around :

```
Template.home.events({
    'click #create-room' : function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        Meteor.call('createNewRoom', function(error, result){
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            }else {
                Session.set("room_id", result);
                Router.go('room', {_id: result});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If I try to use the full link after, like `http://localhost:3000/rooms/eAAHcfwFutRFWHM56` for example, it doesn't work.

Comment: This assumes the rooms are published to the client. Is that the case?

Comment: Right now autopublish is still installed while I set things up so they are.
I can go in the console and do: `Rooms.findOne({_id: 's3iLE9gmnAcCHNuYM'})` and it will return an object, its just not working there.

Comment: if you `console.log(room)` what did you get? an object? on the `checkRoomExists` function

Comment: If I create a room from the main page it returns an object, but if I just use the full link and try it in another browser : `localhost:3000/rooms/eAAHcfwFutRFWHM56` it returns undefined.

Comment: so you want to avoid users create new rooms if they already exists? or Access them if the room exist?

Comment: I am trying to avoid users going to some random ID like `localhost:3000/rooms/asdasd` if a room with that ID doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to avoid users going to some random ID like
>   localhost:3000/rooms/asdasd if a room with that ID doesn't already
>   exist.

If you want to do this you can follow the next.

on the Layout configure add this.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound' //add the notFoundTemplate.
});
```

and this simple `onBeforeAction`.

```
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'room'});
```

Create some sample template like this.

```
<template name="notFound">
 <span> Dam this route don't exist <a href="/">go back to home</a>
</template>
```

**OPTION**

Im not sure if this still working but you can define this on the very last of the `routes.js` js

```
this.route('notFound', {
  path: '*' //this will work like the notFoundTemplate
});
```

**NOTE**

If you don't have layout template use like this.

```
Router.route('/rooms/:_id', {
    name: 'room',
    notFoundTemplate: 'authorNotFound',
    template: 'chatRoom'
});
```

Comment: where is `dataNotFound` coming from in your example?

Comment: that comes with iron router by default

Comment: this `dataNotFound` not only return true when the rout dosnt exist, it will also return true if the data object return `null,undefined`

Comment: But where am I defining what data object it is using if its provided by default? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Look if you have 10 objects inside the `Rooms collection` then you will have 10 avaibles routes ok? so what happened if someone enter `localhost:300:/rooms/123abc` actually this route dosnt exist right? but thats actually a valid a route right? but `123abc` its not an `_id` identifier so that route isn't point anywhere, by this cases `iron:routes` have a special hook called `dataNotFound` so just call it at the bottom of the `routes.js`  `Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'rooms'});`

Comment: Yes that makes sense but I looked at the iron-router documentation and it only uses `dataNotFound` in references to the `data` field defined in route, which isn't what I am doing here.